# Can I control selenium with firefox portable?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver, portable-applications

I have read a lot of articles related to using selenium and portable firefox. But the code doesn't work with me. Did I do something wrong? I am using firefox portable 67 and Geckodriver v0.24.0.

```html
FirefoxDriverService driverService = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService(@"D:\C# Project\FirefoxPortal tesst\FirefoxPortal tesst\bin\Debug\", "geckodriver.exe");
            FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
            //var profile = new FirefoxProfileManager().GetProfile("");
            options.Profile = new FirefoxProfile(@"D:\C# Project\FirefoxPortal tesst\FirefoxPortal tesst\bin\Debug\FirefoxPortable\Data\profile");
            options.BrowserExecutableLocation = @"D:\C# Project\FirefoxPortal tesst\FirefoxPortal tesst\bin\Debug\FirefoxPortable\FirefoxPortable.exe";
            IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(driverService, options);
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://stackoverflow.com/");
```

Comment: "But the code doesn't work with me." Are you getting error messages? If so, you should share those here.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel code not working bro.

Comment: "code not working bro" does not give us enough information to help you. You should be getting some sort of error yet you refuse to share that information with us.

Comment: You know selenium???

Comment: I mean: I want to ask if selenium works with portable firefox. @JustinEzequiel

Comment: Yes. I'm only using portableapps.com versions on both Firefox and Chrome on my machine. I use both with Selenium. Where's your error message?

Comment: I can open the portable. But I cannot use the command: driver.navigate().gotourl(url). OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: 'The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:1955/session timed out after 60 seconds.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not have time today but try changing

```
options.BrowserExecutableLocation = @"D:\C# Project\FirefoxPortal tesst\FirefoxPortal tesst\bin\Debug\FirefoxPortable\FirefoxPortable.exe";
```

to

```
options.BrowserExecutableLocation = @"D:\C# Project\FirefoxPortal tesst\FirefoxPortal tesst\bin\Debug\FirefoxPortable\App\firefox64\firefox.exe";
```

or to wherever you have your firefox.exe file.

Comment: Working Bro. Thanks support me <3

Comment: You should click the up arrow of my answer if this helped you.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score. Sorry bro. I clicked before bro.

Comment: I have more questions bro: How can I save my browser history when using the portable firefox.